# 2nd order ODE with logistic factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve

$$ F''(x) + e(x)b[e(x)F'(x)  - (1-e(x))F(x) ] = 0$$

with $e(x)$ being the logistic function $L/(1-\exp(-k(x-x_0))$. Neither Wolfram Alpha nor Math saga found any solution for this under standard computing time. Is there any transformation that I could do to this? Or how could I proceed?

Comment: You should try applying a Laplace transform to the equation.

Comment: @Jeb I am not so experienced with that: I know that $LF'(x) = LF - F(0)$. But how would I Transform composites as $e(x)F'(x)$?